# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dest_eröff' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, file

```
dest_dir = "I:\\My Drive\\Programmieren\\Buchführung"
        if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
            os.mkdir(dest_dir)
        for file_name in os.listdir(dest_dir):
            if not file_name.startswith("Eröff"):
                start = str(date.today())
                dest_eröff = os.path.join(dest_dir, "Eröffnungbilanz_{}".format(start[:4]))
                with open(dest_eröff, 'w') as file:
                    file.write("Eroeffnungsbilanz ({})".format(start[:4]))
            else:
                dest_eröff = os.path.join(dest_dir, file_name)
        with open(dest_eröff) as file:
            start_year = int(str(file.read())[19:23])
```

Why is that code not working. The title is the Error. I thought the variable "dest_eröff" is assigned in every case (wether the file exists or not). In the case it is not existing it will be created (in dependence of the actual year) and if it exists it just continues and assignes the variable. So it should be alright.

The error occurs for `with open(dest_eröff) as file:`.Thanks for any help I get.

Comment: Your variable is only assigned to in the `else:`. What if there are no file names that start with your string?

Comment: It's also assigned in the `if:`, but neither `if` nor `else` might be executed if `os.listdir(dest_dir)` is empty.

Comment: @mkrieger1: OK, got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if there are no files in your `dest_dir`?

If `os.listdir(dest_dir)` returns an empty list the content of the for loop will not be executed and `dest_eröff` will not be assigned a value.

You can initialize `dest_eröff` to `None` in the beginning and then only attempt to open the file if `dest_eröff` has a value:

```py
dest_dir = "I:\\My Drive\\Programmieren\\Buchführung"
if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
    os.mkdir(dest_dir)

dest_eröff = None

for file_name in os.listdir(dest_dir):
    # your code unchanged

if dest_eröff is not None:
    with open(dest_eröff) as file:
        start_year = int(str(file.read())[19:23])
```